# How to shorten a list in standard ml

Tags: list, sml, smlnj

I just start working with standard ml and really have some trouble understanding the list in this language. So my question is how to shorten a list in ml ? For example, if I have a list [1,2,3,4,5,6], I want to shorten it to [1,2]. What I'm having so far is:

```
fun shorten(i, l) = let val newlen = i in newlen = length l//in correct
```

what I want is a function that will take i as a location that user want to shorten the list and l is the list. In this case, the input should look like `shorten(2, [1,2,3,4,5,6]` and the output should look like `[1,2]`

Comment: Instead of writing random code, what ideas do you have that could be conducive to writing a correct solution?

Comment: The one that I write above is what I got so far, what im trying to do is  to create a variable newlen which equal to i and set it equal to the new length of the list. I'm a beginner with ml so I kinda lost here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function should do it:

```
fun shorten(_, nil) = nil
  | shorten(0, _) = nil
  | shorten(i, x::xs) = x::shorten(i - 1, xs)
```

As you noticed, this function doesn't throw any exceptions when `i` is larger than the length of the list. An approach that uses exceptions would be this:

```
exception IllegalArgument

fun shorten(_, nil) = nil
  | shorten(0, _) = nil
  | shorten(i, x::xs) =
    if i > length(x::xs) then raise IllegalArgument
    else x::shorten(i - 1, xs)
```

In SML you need to declare any exception type with `exception` before it is raised using `raise`. Otherwise, the exception type is not bound in the environment and the interpreter will complain about the symbol being unknown.

Comment: Thank you. May I ask how to check for error with this case ? what I have:
`fun shorten(_, nil) = raise Error
  | shorten(0, _) = raise Error
  | shorten(i, x::xs) = if i > length (x::xs) then raise Error else x::revert((i - 1), xs)<code>&lt;html&gt;</code>`
doesnt seem to be working

Answer (score 1):

The [SML Basis Library](http://sml-family.org/Basis/overview.htm) contains the function `List.take` to perform the required task as part of the [List Structure](http://sml-family.org/Basis/list.htm).

```
- fun shorten ( toHowMany, myList ) =  List.take ( myList, toHowMany ) ;
val shorten = fn : int * 'a list -> 'a list

- shorten ( 2, [1,2,3,4,5,6] ) ;
val it = [1,2] : int list
```

If the order of the arguments doesn't matter, then `List.take` can be used directly:

```
- List.take ( [1,2,3,4], 2 ) ;
val it = [1,2] : int list
```